# Excel VBA Align two shapes to the right with smooth transition

Tags: vba, excel, alignment, transition

When I click on two shapes of different sizes, then click Align Right, Excel 2013 smoothly slides the smaller shape to the right to match the location with the other shape. Is there a way to use/harness that smooth transition with Excel VBA? I've tried the code Selection.ShapeRange.Align mslAlignRights, MSOFalse after selecting the two shapes but it instantly jumps to the right. It works, but it's not animated like I want.

Comment: Doubtful, but it would be nice. I'm curious.